# What's the difference between export interface and export default interface in typescript declaration merging?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, declare

What's the difference between export interface and export default interface in declaration merging ?

I think `export interface` just extend, `export default interface` will override old interface completely.

```js
declare module 'react-intl' {
  export interface MessageDescriptor {
    // error: ts(2717), id's type must be string
    id: 'test' | 'test2';
  }
}
```

if I use :

```js
declare module 'react-intl' {
  export default interface MessageDescriptor {
    // ok
    id: 'test' | 'test2';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you export interface it will only export the specific object from the class but when you export default interface it will export all the objects and override the behavior of previously exported class instances.